# How much damage does a small crafted bomb do?

Tags: dnd-5e, weapons, damage, ranged-attack

If I were to make a bomb using nails, a small wooden barrel of gunpowder, a wick, and wax to seal the whole thing, about how much damage would it do? No buffs, no mods, just a bomb. any ideas?

Would the damage go up if it were a metal barrel? Adding oil or tar?

The way we've been doing it so far, is I take a roll to see how good my PC crafts the bomb. than based upon that roll is the damage. for a poorly made bomb, it usually just lights on fire. no real explosion, for a mid-grade one its usually a 2d6 to everything within a 15 foot range, and for a well made one its 3d10 to everything in range, plus possible force damage, with the possibility of a acrobatics check to dodge and take half damage. Is there anywhere with real standards for this type of weapon?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The *Dungeon Master's Guide* has some rules for explosives in the *Dungeon Master's Workshop* chapter.

Some of it, i.e. a [bomb](https://www.dndbeyond.com/equipment/bomb) is even part of the basic rules.

> As an action, a character can light this bomb and throw it at a point up to 60 feet away. Each creature within 5 feet of that point must succeed on a DC 12 Dexterity saving throw or take 3d6 fire damage.

Based on your description, maybe a [fragmentation grenade](https://www.dndbeyond.com/equipment/grenade-fragmentation) fits better as mechanics/damage type orientation:

> As an action, a character can throw a grenade at a point up to 60 feet away. With a grenade launcher, the character can propel the grenade up to 120 feet away.
>
> Each creature within 20 feet of an exploding fragmentation grenade must make a DC 15 Dexterity saving throw, taking 5d6 piercing damage on a failed save, or half as much damage on a successful one.

If you think the damage is too high, feel free to adjust it based on the check or increase the costs. This is a typical DM fiat question so: **"The DM decides the mechanics and how much damage it deals, the references I posted are just for inspiration."**

Comment: You could probably relate the 150 gp cost suggested for the bomb back to the crafting rules . . . although by RAW, each bomb is going to take a while to make.

Comment: Sounds more like a make-shift claymore than a grenade. Our DI taught how to make them with tape, nails, C4 and an ammo box (which would be smaller than a firkin. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_brewery_cask_units